# background-image not working on github pages (but working on other sections)

Tags: html, css, header, background-image, github-pages

I know there are 3-4 similar post on this but I am still unable to resolve mine at the moment. I'll enumerate below

1. CSS background image (from header and down to sections 1 to 4 it is not loading when I am using GitHub pages) It is working fine with my MS VS Code. (Github page: https://nadin3amanda.github.io/Sunnyside-agency-landing-page/)
2. Section 5 down to footer is working with the same code for both HTML and CSS.
   I tried using a line instead for the URL but it won't work.
3. I also tried using width and height and setting to 100% both but still won't work.

Basically the solutions I found here in StackOverflow won't work.

Please help. below is the HTML code for the header (which was a plain header before but I changed it to class as  part of the solution)

```
<header class="header">
    <div class="menu-wrap">
      <div class="logo-wrap">
        <img src="images/logo.svg" alt="Logo" />
      </div>
      <div class="mobile-icon">
        <img class="mobile-nav" src="images/icon-hamburger.svg" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="main-menu">
        <nav class="menu">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="banner-wrap">
      <h1>We are creatives</h1>
      <a href="#content"
        ><img src="images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="Arrow Down"
      /></a>
    </div>
  </header>
```

While for the css

```
    header {
  padding: 32px 24px 130px;
  background-position: center;
  background-image: url("/images/desktop/image-header.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Github repo is here: https://github.com/nadin3amanda/Sunnyside-agency-landing-page

Answer (score 0):

I think you img links are not work. check it. Or maybe problem with hosting service. Try with another hosting service. Like Vercel or firebase.

check my one.

Repo - https://github.com/lashika-malith/sunnyside-agency

site - https://sunnyside-agency-lac.vercel.app/

Comment: Hi Lashika, thank you for taking notice. What's odd is that the images (section) before the footer are working whereas to has  the same css code as to those in the header and sections 1 to 4...